# Mongo Aggregation Flat nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this structure in Mongo:

```
[
  {
    ProjectId: 111,
    Billings: [
      {
        FieldA: 1
      },
      {
        FieldA: 2
      }
    ],
    Extras: [
      {
        ExtraId: "E_111_01",
        Billings: [
          {
            FieldA: 3
          },
          {
            FieldA: 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        ExtraId: "E_111_02",
        Billings: [
          {
            FieldA: 5
          },
          {
            FieldA: 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    ProjectId: 222,
    Billings: [],
    Extras: [
      {
        ExtraId: "E_222_01",
        Billings: [
          {
            FieldA: 7
          },
          {
            FieldA: 8
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to flat all 'Billings' to root, but some of them are in a first level array and other are 2 levels down.

And the process should add 2 props to 'Billing', the project ID it´s from, and if It´s an Extra, the 'Billings' should have the Project ID and the Extra ID.

How can I flat all to root? Just Unwind 2 times and MergeArray ? to push the IDs to the Billings, should I use MAP?

In this example the result would be:

```
[
    {
        ProjectId: 111,
        FieldA: 1
    },
    {
        ProjectId: 111,
        FieldA: 2
    }
    {
        ProjectId: 111,
        ExtraId: "E_111_01",
        FieldA: 3
    },
    {
        ProjectId: 111,
        ExtraId: "E_111_01",
        FieldA: 4
    }
    {
        ProjectId: 111,
        ExtraId: "E_111_01",
        FieldA: 5
    },
    { 
        ProjectId: 111,
        ExtraId: "E_111_01",
        FieldA: 6
    }
    {
        ProjectId: 222,
        ExtraId: "E_222_01",
        FieldA: 7
    },
    {
        ProjectId: 222,
        ExtraId: "E_222_01",
        FieldA: 8
    }
]
```

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0OkNod-A7g)

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working on the assumption that `FieldA` in your example is a placeholder that might be multiple fields or different names, you might

- $project to combine the top level `Billings` with the `$extras` array
- unwind `Extras` and `Billings` so each document contains only one
- Add the `ProjectId` and `ExtraId` to the billing object
- Promote the `Billings` document to be the root

This will keep any fields in each `Billings` document, and not require that you know the field names ahead of time.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$project": {
      _id: 0,
      ProjectId: 1,
      Extras: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [{ Billings: "$Billings" }],
          "$Extras"
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$Extras"},
  {$unwind: "$Extras.Billings"},
  {$addFields: {
      "Extras.Billings.ExtraId": "$Extras.ExtraId",
      "Extras.Billings.ProjectId": "$ProjectId"
   }},
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$Extras.Billings"
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oU1vCMKM2db)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Extras"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Extras.Billings.ExtraId": "$Extras.ExtraId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "ProjectId": "$ProjectId",
      "Billings": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$Billings",
          "$Extras.Billings"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Billings"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "ProjectId": "$ProjectId",
      "FieldA": "$Billings.FieldA",
      "ExtraId": "$Billings.ExtraId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "id": "$_id",
        "FieldA": "$FieldA",
        "ProjectId": "$ProjectId",
        "ExtraId": "$ExtraId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "FieldA": "$_id.FieldA",
      "ProjectId": "$_id.ProjectId",
      "ExtraIs": "$_id.ExtraId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "ProjectId": 1,
      "FieldA": 1
    }
  }
])
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/DZAIfDY5x7L](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DZAIfDY5x7L)